# Javascript conditional replace not working

Tags: javascript

Javascript conditional replace image src to https if url prefix is in http:// and ignore https:// currently i have this piece of code added to the source part.

**Javascript:**

```
src="' + p.replace("http","https") + '"
```

**The issue:**

`http://` gets replace to `https://` but the problem is its also replacing `https://` to `httpss://` which is breaking the src attribute and images are returning 404 error.
How to fix this issue?

**UPDATE:**

The variable `p` contains image URL which is sometimes http and sometimes its https. the above code replaces http to https successfully but when a url have https it adds another s like this `httpss://` which returns 404 and image cant load

Comment: why can't you try replacing http:// to https://

Comment: @RICKYKUMAR that works. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just expand the selection, so that you are replacing `http://` instead of just `http`, i.e.:

```
p.replace("http://", "https://")
```

See example below:

```js
const urls = [
  'https://example.com',
  'http://example.com'
];

urls.forEach(url => {
  console.log(`Original URL: ${url}`);
  
  // Incorrect behavior
  console.log(url.replace('http', 'https'));
  
  // Correct behavior
  console.log(url.replace('http://', 'https://'));
});
```

---

An alternative way to solve this problem will be to leverage the [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL), which is [supported by anything after IE11](https://caniuse.com/#feat=url). You simply parse your string using the `new URL()` constructor, and then modify its `protocol` property, i.e.:

```js
const urls = [
  'https://example.com',
  'http://example.com'
];

urls.forEach(url => {
  console.log(`Original URL: ${url}`);
  
  const modifiedUrl = new URL(url);
  modifiedUrl.protocol = 'https';
  console.log(modifiedUrl.toString());
});
```

Comment: Actually thats what i'm trying to do. Its working partially. When a url appears as https it adds another s like this `httpss://`

Comment: @yaqoob Well that depends what your `p` variable contains. What's in there? Can you update your question?

Comment: @yaqoob My code should work. Did you even try it? The reason why your code fails is because you are replacing `http`, which also occurs in URLs with `https://...`. By adding the `://` you are ensuring that you only replace `http://`

Comment: Its fixed :-) Thank you for your time Terry. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

It is working fine. But could you please define your code why you add double quotes?

```js
var p = 'http://google.com';

var src= p.replace("http","https");

console.log(src);
```

**UPDATED**

Please have a look to this updated solution.

```js
var p = prompt('Enter URL?');

let str = p.split("://")[0];

var src= str === 'http' ? p.replace("http","https") : p;

console.log(src);
```

Comment: @yaqoob please have look to **updated solution** answer. hope it work for you. If this work for you please leave a reply.

Comment: Thank you Ahsan. The issue has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because your match string, `http`, is a subset of your replace string, `https`.  So you need to suggest not to match `https` strings, or you could say match only `http` that doesn't have an `s` after it.

```js
const urlVariants = [
  'http://www.google.com',
  'https://www.google.com'
]
urlVariants.forEach(url=> {
  console.log( url, '->', url.replace('http:','https:') )
  console.log( url, '->', url.replace(/http([^s])/,"https$1") )
})
```

Comment: Thank you Mike. The issue has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You should match using regular expression. The regular expression to check if the url has uses http is :

```
  /http[^(?=s)]{0}/i
```

Below is the working snippet to replace http by https successfully.

```
"http://www.google.com".replace(/http[^(?=s)]{0}/i,'https')
```

Comment: Thank you Rishu. The issue has been fixed.